# Read mutiple occurances of string from file in python

Tags: python

I am trying to find indexes of multiple occurrences of a character from my file. My code is as under;

```
with open(completeName, 'r') as myfile:
        data=myfile.read()
        for m in re.finditer('K', data):
            result = m.start()
            #print result and do something more
```

Why am I getting the following error;

```
NameError: global name 're' is not defined
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: you need to `import re`

Comment: use `import re`

Comment: Oh, sorry. My bad. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to import your package first: `import re`.

See [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html).